# Using the glossaries package, how can I have a different description in the glossaries list to how it appears in the document?

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

The main reason for this is that in text I would like QUT to appear as "the Queensland University of Technology" but I would like this to appear in the acronym list with out the leading "the".

Is this possible?

If not, what is a good way to deal with acronyms where you need "the" in the long form, but not the short?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set up text to appear in the acronym list as an optional argument `description` of the `\newacronym` command

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym[description=Queensland University of Technology]{QUT}{QUT}{the Queensland University of Technology}

\begin{document}
In \gls{QUT}, they did something.

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]


\end{document}
```

[image]